# microsoft.identitymodel.clients - cannot find this

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, authentication

I'm trying to use azure acs and the windows live, google etc. identity providers as highlighted in this [walkthrough](http://haishibai.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/walkthrough-role-based-security-on.html)

however I am having the problem with the piece of code

```
AuthenticationContext _authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://{your ACS    
namespace}.accesscontrol.windows.net");
AssertionCredential theToken = 
_authContext.AcquireUserCredentialUsingUI("urn:WPFWithAAL");
```

which returns an error that the type or `namespace AssertionCredential cannot be found`. I found  [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.aspx)  which suggest it exists in the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` namespace, but i can't add this namespace because there doesn't seem to be a `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients` namespace that i can add.

Also, when i build the application, it actually returns a slightly different error in the output, `saying Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Authentication.AssertionCredential` is inaccessible due to its protection level. so i am unsure what the actual error really is and how to resolve it.

i am building a WPF 4.5 Desktop Application, that will require authentication and will need to link to "social" accounts such as windows live / google etc. so i need a way to do this. if this is not the way forward, can anyone suggest an alternative method?

Comment: I believe all (or most) of the Microsoft.IdentityModel.* stuff is now in System.IdentityModel with the latest versions of the .NET framework (.net 4.5 and up I *think*)

Comment: thanks, though there still doesn't seem to be a System.Identity.Clients http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145031(v=vs.110).aspx